# extract values from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, extract, overlap

I am using Pandas and would like to extract values from multiple dataframes.
For example, there are three dataframes as below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K0', 'K1'],
                     'A': ['A0', 'A1'],
                     'B': ['B0', 'B1']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K1', 'K22'],
                      'C': ['C1', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D1', 'D3']})

df3 = pd.DataFrame({'key': ['K1', 'K30'],
                      'E': ['E1', 'E3'],
                      'F': ['F1', 'F3']})
```

If key is shared among dataframes, I would like to extract values.
So I did below

```
pd.merge(df1,df2, on='key')
```

This showed below and this was fine.

```
    A   B key   C   D
0  A1  B1  K1  C1  D1
```

However, if I try to do this more than 2 dataframes, it will not work.
For example, following did not work.

```
pd.merge(df1,df2,df3, on='key')
```

I think pd.merge is not suitable for this.
Does anyone know good way to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge can be applied only on two dataframes at a time unlike concat so the solution is to use merge on the first output of merge

```
df1.merge(df2, on='key').merge(df3, on = 'key')
```

gives

```
    A   B   key C   D   E   F
0   A1  B1  K1  C1  D1  E1  F1
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you guys!!

Answer (score 6):

[pd.merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging) works with two dataframes (left and right)

You can use pd.concat concatenate a list of dataframes.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
```

Right...

```
pd.concat([df1.set_index('key'),df2.set_index('key'),df3.set_index('key')],axis=1,join='inner')
```

Comment: pd.concat([df1.set_index('key'),df2.set_index('key'),df3.set_index('key')],axis=1,join='inner')

Comment: `pd.concat([d.set_index('key') for d in [df1, df2, df3]], axis=1, join='inner')`

Answer (score 0):

`pd.merge` does not work for more than 2 dataframes. However, you can try to use `pd.concat`. Check [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a repeated merge like this:

```
df = df1

for right in [df2, df3]:
    df = df.merge(right, on='key')
```

Running this on your data gives:

```
    A   B key   C   D   E   F
0  A1  B1  K1  C1  D1  E1  F1
```

Just have the for loop cover all of the additional dataframes you want to merge with the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Though I am no Pandas expert, I imagine successive calls to `pd.merge` would properly merge them: `pd.merge(pd.merge(df1, df2), df3)`. For programmatic reduction, look at `functools.reduce(pd.merge, dfs)` (where `dfs` is an iterable of dataframes). Pandas might have a built-in solution to better fit, but this will work. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pandas concat function.

code below will give you the result that you are looking for.

```
pd.concat([df1,df2,df3],axis=1)
```

You can find out more that in the pandas Documentation [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html)